# Get current tab index vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabindex

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the currently selected tab index of a form?
Is there an event that handles this changing?(or how to go about making one)
Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no property "tab index" for a form. Do you mean that you want to know which control has user focus, or did you mean that you're using a tab control?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you would want the `TabIndex` property of the `ActiveControl` of the form.  Just note that nested controls will have an index inside their `Parent`, which will have its own index inside its `Parent` and so on, right up to form.

As for events, you'd have to register a method to handle the `Enter` event of each relevant child control.  In that method, the `sender` parameter would refer to the control that just received focus.